# When do surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^4$ intersect all their translations in one direction?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry

I am looking for research or references on the following problem.

Let $S$ be a smoothly embedded connected surface in $\mathbb{R}^4$, with or without boundary. Fix some axis in $\mathbb{R}^4$, let $d \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $S+d$ be the surface obtained by shifting $S$ by $d$ along the chosen axis.

Call $S$ a *periodic surface* if there exists a nonzero $d$ such that $S = S+d$.

Call $S$ a *nicely periodic surface* if for every $d$ and $e$ in $\mathbb{R}$, the intersection of $S+d$ and $S+e$ is non-empty.

> Under what conditions is a periodic surface also nicely periodic?

This question is motivated by the case where the periodic surface $S$ has its boundary restricted to a hyperplane, the whole surface lies on one side of this hyperplane, and $S/(x \sim x+d)$ is diffeomorphic to a Möbius strip. I'm hoping to show that this is nicely periodic.

I claim that if this holds for a particular family of Möbius strips, then the *smooth inscribed rectangle conjecture* is true. This is the conjecture that every smooth Jordan curve has an inscribed rectangle of any given aspect ratio. Of course finding appropriate conditions on $S$, and then testing them on my family of surfaces, would be a hard problem in itself, so I don't feel any closer to solving the rectangle problem.

An analog of this in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is that any periodic curve is nicely periodic, where periodic curves are defined analogously (connected, smoothly embedded, etc), and the proof is by a slight generalization of the Borsuk-Ulam theorem.

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, a sufficient condition for a periodic surface to be nicely periodic is that some plane parallel to the chosen axis intersects the surface in a connected curve.

But in $\mathbb{R}^3$, many periodic surfaces are not nicely periodic, such as a helicoid with the central line removed, or a thin cylinder twisted into a helix with enough space between each twist:

[image: Picture of such a twisted cylinder]

Since I cannot visualize in four dimensions, my results stop here, except for trivial things like inclusions of nicely periodic surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ into $\mathbb{R}^4$.

How can I approach this problem, or what work is there on similar problems?

Comment: If you like the sufficient condition in $\mathbb R^3$ then the same condition in $\mathbb R^4$ will work: if there is a $2$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^4$ parallel to the chosen axis that intersects the surface is a connected curve.